# How we can use optional published var?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

I got a ObservableObject-Class which has a optional published var and I am giving this to ForEach, because I did not initialized my published, even after lunch of my app ForEach should not work. and that is okay, how I can correctly type it in my code?

```
struct PersonData: Identifiable
{
    let id  = UUID()
    var name: String
}


class PersonDataModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var persones: [PersonData]?
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var personDataModel = PersonDataModel()
    
    var body: some View {

        HStack
        {
             ForEach( personDataModel.persones != nil ? personDataModel.persones! : [] ) { person in 
                 Text(person.name)  // ← : Here
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if your array is empty, its already not going to render, so if thats the case, no need to make it optional, right?

Comment: you mean instead of      **Published var persones: [PersonData]?**      using this  **Published var persones: [PersonData] = [] **             ?

Comment: Yes, an empty array may be a better solution than the optional.

Comment: thanks @pawello2222, is it okay we initialize our Published inside ContentView, or it is better done it inside ObservableObject-Class? which way is the best?

Comment: You can just do `@Published var persones: [PersonData] = []` as suggested before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you wanted this

```
HStack
{
    ForEach(personDataModel.persones ?? [] ) { person in Text(person.name) }
}
```

Comment: In my way I check if it is not nil then I do unwrapping, but you are using other way, is your way the best way for this job(I mean working with optional) ?

Comment: I'd say it is more swift-y